# How do I make my live templates in Android Studio to generate code like getters and setters according to variables that have already existed?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, getter-setter, live-templates

now I have made one like this:

```
public $type$ get$Property$() { return $property$; }
public void set$Property$($type$ $property$) { this.$property$ = $property$; }
```

WHERE:

```
type:complete()
property:suggestVariableName()
Property:capitalize(property)
```

it can generate code like this:

```
public  get() {
    return ;
}

public void set( ) {
    this. = ;
}
```

but this is not what I want.

I want to generate getters and setters according to the variables,and don't have to input the types and names of variable again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want setter and getter fot the variable you can use the default way of insertion. Press `ALt` + `Insert`. Then choose getter and setter. You will be shown a dialogue box with all your variable names. You can select variable there. You can also select multiple variable.
Notice you might have to press `Fn` also to press `Insert`.
This is not the answer you want but it does the work you want.